# Python - for loop fails when passing datetime object back as a string

Tags: python, string, datetime, amazon-web-services

I'm very new to coding and Python and i'm stuck with this for loop.  Basically for each AWS Workspace (VDI machine) i am trying to return the Workspace name and the last time it was logged onto.  These metrics are easily available using 'describe_workspaces_connection_status.

At first it failed with:

```
Calling DescribeWorkspaces()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./ws-conectionTS.py", line 20, in <module>
print "Workspace name " + item["WorkspaceId"] + " last connected on : " +   item["LastKnownUserConnectionTimestamp"]
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, datetime.datetime found
```

After some Googling I realised I needed to pass the datetime object as a string so added str():

```
print "Workspace name " + item["WorkspaceId"] + " last connected on : " +  str(item["LastKnownUserConnectionTimestamp"])
```

Now when I run the code it returns the data for the first Workspace but then errors:

```
Calling DescribeWorkspaces()
Workspace name ws-qaazwssx last connected on : 2016-12-05  17:27:40.617000+00:00
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./ws-conectionTS.py", line 20, in <module>
print "Workspace name " + item["WorkspaceId"] + " last connected on : " +  str(item["LastKnownUserConnectionTimestamp"])
KeyError: 'LastKnownUserConnectionTimestamp'
```

Can someone please advise how I can change the code so it will return the data for each item in the loop?
Heres the complete code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import boto3
import datetime
import time

wsclient = boto3.client('workspaces')

nextToken = ""

while 1:

    if nextToken == "":
        print "Calling DescribeWorkspaces()"
        workspaces = wsclient.describe_workspaces_connection_status()
    else:
        print "Calling DescribeWorkspaces(NextToken=" + nextToken + ")"
        workspaces =      wsclient.describe_workspaces_connection_status(NextToken=nextToken)

    for item in workspaces["WorkspacesConnectionStatus"]:
        print "Workspace name " + item["WorkspaceId"] + " last connected on :   " + str(item["LastKnownUserConnectionTimestamp"])

    if workspaces.has_key("NextToken"):
    nextToken = workspaces["NextToken"]
    else:
        break
```

The response from 'describe_workspaces_connection_status' is:

```
{
    'WorkspacesConnectionStatus': [
        {
            'WorkspaceId': 'string',
            'ConnectionState': 'CONNECTED'|'DISCONNECTED'|'UNKNOWN',
            'ConnectionStateCheckTimestamp': datetime(2015, 1, 1),
            'LastKnownUserConnectionTimestamp': datetime(2015, 1, 1)
        },
    ],
    'NextToken': 'string'
}
```

many thanks!

Comment: It looks like it worked properly on the first iteration, then failed on the second. Suggesting that some items do not have the same existing keys. Instead of accessing items like `item["key"]` try using `item.get("key")` which will return `None` if the key doesn't exist or `item.get("key", "What I want if the key is not found")`

Comment: The code you posted is not the code you are running (missing indentation after the `if`). Also, we could help better if we knew what `wsclient` or at least `workspaces` and `item` are.

Comment: It seems LastKnownUserConnectionTimestamp its empty on the second try... Can you try to run the code without this field to check it?

Comment: @sytech - perfect worked like a charm :)

Comment: @hop - This is the code I am running.  I might have missed the indentation when formatting it in this post (go easy on me its my 1st ever one :)). Those first 2 are just variables defined within the code used to make the api call. The 'item' is an arbitrary variable in the for loop to iterate over the results.

Comment: @hop - This is the response syntax from 'describe_workspaces_connection_status'

The response from 'describe_workspaces_connection_status' is :

{
    'WorkspacesConnectionStatus': [
        {
            'WorkspaceId': 'string',
            'ConnectionState': 'CONNECTED'|'DISCONNECTED'|'UNKNOWN',
            'ConnectionStateCheckTimestamp': datetime(2015, 1, 1),
            'LastKnownUserConnectionTimestamp': datetime(2015, 1, 1)
        },
    ],
    'NextToken': 'string'
}

Cheers

Comment: @vlucid: i did go easy on you, i didn't downvote ;)
you should update your question with the data structure instead of putting it in a comment!

Comment: @hop - thanks for the tip.  I think thats done now although i couldn't figure out how to format the json so it looks a bit friendlier in the post.

Comment: @vlucid: you were simply missing an empty line before the block.

Comment: @hop: Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to sytech for the answer - working code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import boto3
import datetime
import time

wsclient = boto3.client('workspaces')

nextToken = ""

while 1:

    if nextToken == "":
        print "Calling DescribeWorkspaces()"
        workspaces = wsclient.describe_workspaces_connection_status()
    else:
        print "Calling DescribeWorkspaces(NextToken=" + nextToken + ")"
        workspaces =   wsclient.describe_workspaces_connection_status(NextToken=nextToken)

    for item in workspaces["WorkspacesConnectionStatus"]:
        print "Workspace name " + item["WorkspaceId"] + " last connected on : " + str(item.get("LastKnownUserConnectionTimestamp"))

    if workspaces.has_key("NextToken"):
        nextToken = workspaces["NextToken"]
    else:
        break
```